# I get a syntax error when I try to use array map function in Google Scripts. Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I get a syntax error when I insert this particular line

```
pp = pp.map(x => precise(x));
```

into my code. No other line gets the same error, and the code runs fine without this line. Please note that I am using google scripts editor.

`pp` is an array.

The function `precise` is coded like this.

```
function precise(x) {
  return Number.parseFloat(x).toPrecision(3);
}
```

I have isolated the code and tried it out in another online JavaScript editor, which works without a problem.

Is it a problem with Google Apps Script?

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: Syntax error. (line 67, file "Code")Dismiss

Comment: line 67 refers to `pp = pp.map(x => precise(x));`

Comment: But what is the actual error?

Comment: Have you tried `pp = pp.map(precise);`??

Comment: @Satpal that actually works!!!! Thanks. But WHY?

Comment: @JackBashford im rather new to programming, the error occurs when i try to save my code in google apps script

Comment: Does the error occur when you change the code to `pp = pp.map(function(x) { precise(x) });` or what was suggested by @Satpal?

Comment: @YellowSkies ```precise = function (x) {
  return Number.parseFloat(x).toPrecision(3);
}``` so essentially the map function is as follows: `pp = pp.map(function (x) {
  return Number.parseFloat(x).toPrecision(3);
});` I had to think about it for a second as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that Google Apps Scripts is compatible with ES6 syntax such as arrow functions?

You could try changing your code to the following and see if it solves the issue:

```
pp = pp.map(function(x) { return precise(x) });
```

Comment: dear using you method error will surely go, but the returned value is not used at all. So You need to make it `return precise(x)`

Comment: You are correct @Satpal thank you. I edited my answer to `return` the value. @YellowSkies, please take note, you need to `return precise(x)` if you are using my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As the method `precise` returns the string, You can directly pass the function reference to `.map()` method

```
pp = pp.map(precise);
```

or, You could do

```
pp = pp.map(function(x) { return precise(x) });
```

Comment: Very interesting. I've never seen that syntax before. Do you happen to know how `x` is passed to `precise` as first argument?

Comment: @mepley, _how x is passed to precise_ In same fashion it is passed to `function(x) { return precise(x) }`

Comment: Okay, yes of course that works now that I think about it. I like that syntax a lot. It's very concise.